# selecting specific control from a cell that contains multiple controls

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the last column of my asp .net GridView I have an image and a checkbox. I want to check if that checkbox is checked, for all rows. I am getting null reference exception at `if` cause maybe chk is null. any help?

```
try
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in grdSurveyDetails.Rows)
    {
        int index = row.Cells.Count - 1;
        CheckBox chk = row.Cells[index].Controls[1] as CheckBox;
        int rowIndex = row.RowIndex;
        if (chk.Checked)
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "alert", "<script>alert("+rowIndex+" is checked!);</script>");
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{  
    throw;
}
```

Comment: Can you debug the Type of `row.Cells[index].Controls[1]` ?

Comment: Instead of `Controls[1]` you could use `CheckBox chk = row.Cells[index].FindControl("ID_Of_Control") as CheckBox;`

Comment: @Ferus7 yes I dubugged and its null

Comment: @RojalinSahoo thanks buddy it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you populate the gridview via code, so that you always have an image and checkbox in that last cell. If that's the case, something that come to my mind is that you may be accessing the header row which does not have the checkbox in there.

Nonetheless, could you try doing the null check in there, something like

```
if (chk?.Checked)
```

That ? is doing a null check for you. If it's null, then do not do anything with that row.

NB: if the cell doesn't always contains image and checkbox, then use caution as you may have a checkbox in that cell which wasn't at index 1 (ie: you may consider using @Rojalin Sahoo approach to search for checkbox explicitly)

Answer (score 0):

You can check all checked like this
Lets say you have

**Aspx**

```
<asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRow" runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Then in

**Code Behind**

```
 foreach (GridViewRow row in grdSurveyDetails.Rows)
{
    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        int index = row.Cells.Count - 1;
        CheckBox chkRow = (row.Cells[index].FindControl("chkRow") as CheckBox);
        if (chkRow.Checked)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Please look at this complete example
[Here](http://asp.net-informations.com/gridview/checkbox.htm)